# How to select a button from each of multiple button groups (non-radio) in Bootstrap simultaniously

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

If I select a button from one group it works fine. But then if I select a button from the next group it forgets the first groups selection. This is an issue I've seen posted on Stack Overflow many times and each time the solution has been to give each button in the group a different name from the other group. However I've tried this solution and I still can only select a button from one button group at a time. What else could be causing this?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/button-group/

Please see my code below:

```
<form method=”POST”>
        <div id="friendly" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">ESG Consideration (select one)</span>
          </div>
          <button name="friendly" value="very-high" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Very High</button>
          <button name="friendly" value="high" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">  High   </button>
          <button name="friendly" value="medium" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"> Medium  </button>
          <button name="friendly" value="low" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">   Low   </button>
          <button name="friendly" value="very-low" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"> Very Low</button>
        </div>

        <div id="risk-tolerance" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">Risk Tolerance (select one)</span>
          </div>
          <button name="risk-tolerance" value="very-high" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Very High</button>
          <button name="risk-tolerance" value="high" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">  High   </button>
          <button name="risk-tolerance" value="medium" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"> Medium  </button>
          <button name="risk-tolerance" value="low" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">   Low   </button>
          <button name="risk-tolerance" value="very-low" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"> Very Low</button>
        </div>
        <p> </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're misunderstanding the documentation. Buttons are *buttons* there is no way to indicate they are checked or not, as they are not inputs. From your documentation link

> Add on optional JavaScript radio and checkbox style behavior with our [buttons plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#button-plugin).

If you convert this from buttons to inputs it works as expected. (Note: Stack snippets aren't great with bootstrap)

To clarify, a button group is a design, not a functionality. You need to actually use inputs as either checkboxes, or more likely radios.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form method=”POST”>
  <div id="friendly" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">ESG Consideration (select one)</span>
    </div>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="friendly" value="very-high" type="radio">Very High
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="friendly" value="high" type="radio"> High
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="friendly" value="medium" type="radio"> Medium
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="friendly" value="low" type="radio"> Low
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="friendly" value="very-low" type="radio"> Very Low
            </label>
  </div>

  <div id="risk-tolerance" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">Risk Tolerance (select one)</span>
    </div>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="risk-tolerance" value="very-high" type="radio">Very High
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="risk-tolerance" value="high" type="radio"> High
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="risk-tolerance" value="medium" type="radio"> Medium
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="risk-tolerance" value="low" type="radio"> Low
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="risk-tolerance" value="very-low" type="radio"> Very Low
            </label>
  </div>
  <p> </p>

</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much for responding. In the documentation  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#button-plugin  it says that I can use a method ```$().button('toggle')``` to show that the button has been selected. As of now, the code does not show its been selected after I click it in the browser. Do you know how I might add that?